# What happens if I divide $x$ by $\infty$?

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

The definition of $e$ is if $n$ is equal to $\infty$

[image]By that definition can I algebraic manipulate the equation and say that $r/\infty=e^{(1/\infty)}-1$?

Comment: ................. no.

Comment: i don't know about algebraic manipulation but yes that is correct

Comment: $$\begin{array}{ll} \rm no: & r/\infty = e^{1/\infty}-1 \\ \rm yes: & \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+r/n)^n=e^r \end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite make sense to divide by $\infty$, but conceptually it's accurate. $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{r}{x}=0$$
while 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=1$$

So the expression you have is technically correct, although you should really use limits to express it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$A=P\left(1+\frac r n \right)^{nt}$$ take logarithms $$\log(A)=\log(P)+nt \log\left(1+\frac r n \right)$$ When $n$ is large, using equivalents which make $$\log\left(1+\frac r n \right)\sim \frac r n$$ and then $$\log(A)\sim\log(P)+nt\times\frac r n=\log(P)+rt\implies A=Pe^{rt}$$